# jsdom.env is not a function exporting svg to image

Tags: node.js, d3.js, jsdom

I am trying to convert a d3 svg image to an image based on the following tutorial: https://github.com/hugolpz/svgcreator.node.js

I install the following statements:

```
sudo npm install -g jsdom d3js
npm install jsdom d3js
node svgcreator.node.js > out.svg
```

I used the following code

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
jsdom.env(
  "<html><body></body></html>",        // CREATE DOM HOOK
  [ 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js',    // JS DEPENDENCIES online ...
  'js/d3.v3.min.js' ],                 // ... & local-offline

  function (err, window) {

// D3JS CODE * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
    var svg = window.d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("id", "rect1")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("width", 80)
        .attr("height", 80)
        .style("fill", "green");
// END (D3JS) * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

  //PRINTING OUT SELECTION
    console.log( window.d3.select("body").html() );
 } // end function
);
```

When i execute **node svgcreator.node.js > out.svg** i get the following error

```
TypeError: jsdom.env is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ErikvanderHoeven\Documents\git\svgcreator.node.js\svgcreator.node.js:5:7)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47?[39
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a dependency version issue - the code in the Github project is several years old and the instructions are loading much later versions of the dependencies than when the example code was written.

I get an npm error trying to install `d3js` and `jsdom` is on v16.4. If I run:

```
npm install jsdom d3 --save
```

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "test-jsdom",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^6.5.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0"
  }
}
```

Github user [dam1r89](https://gist.github.com/dam1r89) shows a way to do what you are trying on later versions in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tomgp/c99a699587b5c5465228).

My take on it:

```
const d3 = require("d3");
const fs = require("fs");
const {JSDOM} = require("jsdom");

// init d3 - https://gist.github.com/tomgp/c99a699587b5c5465228
const minHtml = "<html><head></head><body></body></html>";
const dom = new JSDOM(`${minHtml}`, { pretendToBeVisual: true });
const window = dom.window;
window.d3 = d3.select(window.document); 

// D3JS CODE * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
var svg = window.d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100);

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("id", "rect1")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("width", 80)
  .attr("height", 80)
  .style("fill", "green");
// END (D3JS) * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

console.log( window.d3.select("body").html() );
```

Which outputs:

```
<svg width="100" height="100"><rect id="rect1" x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" style="fill: green;"></rect></svg>
```