# D3.CSV ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: d3.js, jsdom

I want to export only the SVG of the "Radial Stacked Barchart" using [jsdom.env is not a function exporting svg to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215608/jsdom-env-is-not-a-function-exporting-svg-to-image) for the "Radial Stacked Barchart" I use the following article: https://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/9f3932d3c7154f8ab3ea2078b2aca113

I created two scripts

**ExportToSVG.js** script:

```
const d3 = require("d3");
const fs = require("fs");
const {JSDOM} = require("jsdom");

// init d3 - https://gist.github.com/tomgp/c99a699587b5c5465228
const minHtml = '<html><head></head><body><svg width="960" height="800" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10"></body></html>'
const dom = new JSDOM(`${minHtml}`, { pretendToBeVisual: true });
const window = dom.window;
window.d3 = d3.select(window.document);

// D3JS CODE * * * * * *  WORKS  * * * * * * * * * * *
var svg = window.d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    innerRadius = 180,
    outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2.5,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var xScaleOffset = Math.PI * 75/180;
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([xScaleOffset, 2 * Math.PI + xScaleOffset])
    .align(0);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#a1d76a", "#91bfdb"]); 

var zClasses = ['внутренняя сторона', 'внешняя сторона'];

// END (D3JS) * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *


// D3JS CODE * * * * * *  EXPIRIMENT  * * * * * * * * * * *
d3.csv("simple_stat.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
    d.left_lane = (+d.left_lane);
    d.right_lane =  (+d.right_lane);
    return d;
  }, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
  
    var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
    var meanAccidents = d3.mean(data, function(d) { return d3.sum(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })
  
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.km; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return (d.left_lane + d.right_lane); })]);
    z.domain(data.columns.slice(1));
  
    // Accidents
    g.append('g')
        .selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.stack().keys(data.columns.slice(1))(data))
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(function(d) { return y(d[0]); })
            .outerRadius(function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
            .startAngle(function(d) { return x(d.data.km); })
            .endAngle(function(d) { return x(d.data.km) + x.bandwidth(); })
            .padAngle(0.01)
            .padRadius(innerRadius));
  
    //yAxis and Mean
  
    var yAxis = g.append("g")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
  
    var yTicksValues = d3.ticks(0, 40, 4);
  
    console.log('Среднее: ', meanAccidents);
  
    // Mean value line
    var yMeanTick = yAxis
      .append("g")
      .datum([meanAccidents]);
  
    yMeanTick.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#C0625E")
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5 3")
        .attr("r", y);
  
    var yTick = yAxis
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(yTicksValues)
      .enter().append("g");
  
    yTick.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#ccdcea")
        .attr("r", y);
  
    yTick.append("text")
        .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d); })
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#fff")
        .attr("stroke-width", 5)
        .text(y.tickFormat(5, "s"));
  
    yTick.append("text")
        .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d); })
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .text(y.tickFormat(5, "s"));
  
    yAxis.append("text")
        .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(yTicksValues.pop()); })
        .attr("dy", "-2em")
        .text("МКАД, аварийность");
  
    // Labels for xAxis
  
    var label = g.append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + ((x(d.km) + x.bandwidth() / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")translate(" + innerRadius + ",0)"; });
  
    label.append("line")
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return (((d.km % 5) == 0) | (d.km == '1')) ? -7 : -4 })
        .attr("stroke", "#000");
  
    label.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return (x(d.km) + x.bandwidth() / 2 + Math.PI / 2) % (2 * Math.PI) < Math.PI ? "rotate(90)translate(0,16)" : "rotate(-90)translate(0,-9)"; })
        .text(function(d) { 
          var xlabel = (((d.km % 5) == 0) | (d.km == '1')) ? d.km : '';
          return xlabel; });
  
  // Legend
    var legend = g.append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(zClasses)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(-50," + (i - (zClasses.length - 1) / 2) * 25+ ")"; });
  
    legend.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 8)
        .attr("fill", z);
  
    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", 15)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
  
  });

console.log( window.d3.select("body").html() );
```

For the data I use the same data as what is described in the example in the above url. When I execute the following statement

```
node ExportToSVG > out.svg
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\git\svgcreator.node.js\node_modules\d3-fetch\dist\d3-fetch.js:32
  return fetch(input, init).then(responseText);
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
    at text (C:\Users\username\Documents\git\svgcreator.node.js\node_modules\?[4md3-fetch?[24m\dist\d3-fetch.js:32:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\Documents\git\svgcreator.node.js\node_modules\?[4md3-fetch?[24m\dist\d3-fetch.js:38:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\Documents\git\svgcreator.node.js\ExportToSVG.js:36:4)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47?[39m
```

Can you please help me

Manny thanks
Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following should work for you.

[source](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/issues/19#issuecomment-379856542)

> You need an environment that supports the Fetch API, such as a a web browser. **Node does not currently support Fetch**, though it may in the future. If you want to load this library in an environment that does not natively support Fetch **you will need to load your own polyfill such as node-fetch.**

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @uhetz's accepted answer, this [comment](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/issues/19#issuecomment-391318445) provides a helpful implementation example for Node:

`npm install node-fetch-polyfill`

```js
if (typeof fetch !== 'function') {
    global.fetch = require('node-fetch-polyfill');
}
const csv = require('d3-fetch').csv;
```