# How to use d3.js and node?

Tags: node.js, d3.js

Using npm to install d3 and and then using

```
var d3 = require("d3"),
    jsdom = require("jsdom");

var document = jsdom.jsdom(),
    svg = d3.select(document.body).append("svg");
```

as mentioned on the d3 documentation does not work because require cannot be used with d3.Using import statement breaks other libraries that I want to use.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215608/jsdom-env-is-not-a-function-exporting-svg-to-image/66218502#66218502

Answer (score 1):

[d3-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-node) might be a suitable solution for you.

It uses `jsdom` in the background but does all the heavy-lifting for you :)

Quoting the example SVG creation code:

```
const D3Node = require('d3-node')
const d3n = new D3Node()      // initializes D3 with container element
d3n.createSVG(10,20).append('g') // create SVG w/ 'g' tag and width/height

d3n.svgString() // output: <svg width=10 height=20 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g></g></svg>
```